# Does eclipse still work for android development.?

Tags: eclipse, development-environment, mobile-development

Basically I'm asking is if I was to download eclipse right now(8/3/17), would I still be able to get all the required plugins to effectively develop android applications.
if so can some one tell me where I could get them.? Everyone keeps sending me to the android studio page but I can't find a link to the stand alone sdk without downloading android studio
Any help  will be appreciated

Comment: You can download Eclipse, but Android Studio is recommended: https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html  Here is a link for eclipse: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-android-developers/neonm6

Comment: I already have eclipse neon for java. but it won't let me create a new android application.
does the android SDK come with eclipse got android?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads) you can find the SDK tools package.